# biblatex: online -> "o. J." when date = {}

Tags: biblatex, online

I have a little problem with my bibliography.
When i dont write a date in this field, there is only

> ()

in the bibliography, mainly in @online citations.

Tex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}                      
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}         
\usepackage{lmodern}            
\usepackage{siunitx}                
\usepackage{url}                    
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}    

%% Literatur Allgemein
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
style=numeric,                                          
sorting=none,                                           
maxbibnames=3,                                          
]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{latexlit.bib}

%% Definiert Online Eintrag
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{ 
    andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},                      % et al. an Stelle von u.a.
    urlseen = {Abruf am},                               % Url-Notiz ändern
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}{% 
    \printnames{author}% 
    \iffieldundef{year} 
    {} 
    { \mkbibparens{% 
            \printfield{year}} 
    } 
    \newunit\newblockpunct 
    \printfield{title}% 
    \setunit*{.\space}% 
    %\newunit\newblock 
    \printfield{url}% 
    \setunit*{.\space}% 
    \printurldate% 
    \finentry
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\newline URL: \url{#1}}        % URL mit \newline ausgeben

\begin{document}
    Dies ist ein Test \autocite{traeger}.               
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Bib File:

```
@Online{traeger,
    author = {Geldsetzer und Schäfers GmbH},
    title = {WG-Stahlschieber online},
    date = {},
    url = {https://www.geldsetzer.de/stahlschieber/online/itraegerschmal.html},
    urldate =   {2019-04-09}
}
```

Result:

[image]

How can I print "o. J." in () ?

Comment: Note that your redefinition of the bibliography driver misses some common bibliography macros that are present in all standard drivers: `usebibmacro{bibindex}`, `\usebibmacro{begentry}`, `\usebibmacro{finentry}` (which is possibly more than just `\finentry`) and the `related` macros. The output won't change a lot, but consistency can be important if you want to make use of `biblatex` standard idioms. Instead of `\setunit*{.\space}` one would normally write `\setunit*{\addperiod\space}` as that can clean up some cases of spurious spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here.

In your redefinition of `@online` citations, you have (comments added by me):

```
\iffieldundef{year}% if the year of publication is undefined,
    {}             %   do nothing;
    { \mkbibparens{% otherwise, print a pair of parentheses
            \printfield{year}} % with the year inside
    }
```

Which means: "If the year of publication is undefined, do nothing; otherwise, print a pair of parentheses with the year inside."

However, in your citation example, the year is *not* undefined, it's just empty (`date = {}`), so it uses the second option.

So you need to

- Remove the `date = {}` from the bib file, so that it counts as "year not defined", and
- Change the "undefined year" branch to the behaviour you want - by replacing the above piece of code with

```
\iffieldundef{year}% if the year of publication is undefined,
    { \mkbibparens{% print parentheses
            o. J.}% with "o. J." inside
    }
    { \mkbibparens{% otherwise, print a pair of parentheses
            \printfield{year}}% with the year inside
    }
```

"If the year of publication is undefined, print "(o. J.)"; otherwise, print a pair of parentheses with the year inside."

Comment: The fact  that `date = {},` does not yield an empty `year` seems to be an artefact of the date parsing done by Biber and is not usual behaviour (for all other fields `<field> = {},` should give you an undefined/empty field in the sense of `\iffieldundef`). I usually suggest to avoid bare formatting commands like `\mkbibparens` in bibmacros, they don't work well together with the punctuation tracker. Instead it is better to use `\printtext` or the field format settings. I am also quite strongly opposed to hard-coded strings like `o. J.` and would normally prefer bibstrings here. ...

Comment: ... In fact there is a bibstring that should almost do the right thing `nodate`, but by default it prints `o.D.` in German not `o.J.` (of course that can be changed with `\DefineBibliographyStrings`).

Comment: Forgot to add the link to the Biber issue: https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/265

Comment: The inconsistent behaviour of `date = {},` in this instance should be fixed in the next Biber release (see link above).